Taurus blazemeter is failing test because of accent in the string field
I have a test in Jmeter that has a request with string field and accent in the string.
When i run that test with Jmeter it runs successfully.
When i run that test with Taurus Blazemeter it gives me [Bad Request]
I have been looking what's wrong with the request few days and after all i got it.
Test just fails because one of the string fields of the request has an accent, it does not fail if i run it with Jmeter, but when i run it with bzt it always gives me [Bad Request], when i remove the accent from the string, it runs successfully.
Example:

{
   "Foo" : "Bar" // Runs successfully
}

{
   "Foo" : "Bár" // Bad Request
}

Is this a bug? is there any solution to this?

I cannot reproduce your issue, maybe there is something to do with your file.encoding
You can create an issue in Taurus project and describe your scenario in details
If you're a BlazeMeter Customer you can open a BlazeMeter Support Ticket
In the meantime as a workaround I can only suggest trying replacing the diacritic with the Unicode escape sequence like:
{
   "Foo" : "B\u00E1r"
}


After you sad me about file encoding, i've looked for it and yes, the problem was in the encoding.
There's parameter in Jmeter to change the encoding to whatever you want for the request, so i added UTF-8 there and now it works correctly.
Thank you very much.
